# Corda transaction chain DAG or blockchain

Tags: corda

Which concept is used for creating a transaction chain in Corda? Is the chain formed is based on Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) or any other chaining concept. In Corda, there is no concept of the single-chain using genesis block

Answer (score 0):

Corda makes use of the [UTXO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspent_transaction_output) model. The [key concepts](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-transactions.html) section contains a good introduction of how this model works in practice.

> In Corda, there is no concept of the single-chain using genesis block

Correct, in Corda there can be multiple, normal transactions that contain only output states and no input states.